# Backup table does not replicate geometry, fed by trigger in pgAdmin (postGIS)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, trigger

I have two tables, A and B. B is a backup of A.

Table A has a trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON A
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_function();
```

And the trigger function:

```sql
INSERT INTO B ( 
        id,
        geom
)
VALUES (
    OLD.id,
    OLD.geom
);
    return null;
```

Tables A and B have full rights, both have a primary key (id for A and B has its own).

My idea is that this will fill table B with the points made/changed in table A, and those points can be kept as a backup. This works for for all fields I try except geom, for some reason geom can't be written to B by the trigger. I have populated B with points without issue through FME and can work with them fine in QGIS, so the issue (I assume) must be with my trigger setup or pgAdmin.

Any clues as to why geom can't be transferred?

Comment: `INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` - not a good idea.
Can you show the definitions for your tables "A" and "B"? Perhaps the problem is in the primary key sequence. It is better to store the OLD.id without unique constraint in a separate “previous_id” field.

Comment: A:s id is only a field in B, not the primary key. so no unique constraint, i just wanted to bring it along so i can join based on it later if i wanted to, or to find events on that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Row-level* triggers gain access to the transitional state of each respective row via the trigger-level *variables* `OLD` & `NEW` - **however**, the state of these *variables* are **dependent on the trigger *operation***:

- `ON INSERT/UPDATE` triggers have access to values in `NEW`
- `ON DELETE/UPDATE` triggers have access to values in `OLD`

I.e. for `INSERT` *operations* the *variable* `OLD` does not hold any values other than `NULL`!

---

The respective [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER) have a [comprehensive example for an audit table trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE), showing the conditional access to these *variables* based on the *operation*.

Here tailored to your example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
      INSERT INTO B ( id, geom ) VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.geom );
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO B ( id, geom ) VALUES ( OLD.id, OLD.geom );
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
  END;
  $$
;
```

Since these *variables* will be `NULL` if not supported by the operation, your example could be simplified to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO B ( id, geom ) VALUES
      ( COALESCE(OLD.id, NEW.id), COALESCE(OLD.geom, NEW.geom) )
    ;

    RETURN NULL;
  END;
  $$
;
```

Comment: That was it, thank you!